# NSData setLength EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am developing an IOS application. setLength method crash in didReceiveResponse. What do you think is the reason for this. What should I do prevent.

[image]

```
- (void) callService:(NSString*)urlString
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlString]];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection) {
        self.webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"connection is NULL");
    }

}

#pragma mark Web service

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.webData appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: check your console...you are getting `connection is NULL` printed

Comment: The exception message states that setLenght: is called on an *array*. Set a breakpoint in didReceiveResponse and check the self.webData object.

Comment: Did you try to run your app with "Zombies enabled" to find possible memory management problems?

Comment: There are a lot of web service. I don't know Which service :(

Comment: Where's the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` from the title?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a crash on `NSData` usages are in fact an early release problem. A NSData initialized with `[NS(Mutable)Data data]` is an autoreleasable object, even though you called a `retain` on it.

To be sure this object doesn't get released before your `didReceiveResponse` gets called, initialize it with `[[NSMutableData alloc] init]`. That should do it

Comment: This is not quite correct. Retaining the object increases the reference count, so it will not be deleted, even when the current autorelease pool ends.

Comment: As this keeps getting upvotes I feel obliged to back up Martin: This answer is confusing ("autoreleasable" is not a thing) and gives pointless advice (`[[NSMutableData alloc] init]` is not different from `[[NSMutableData data] retain]` from the ownership perspective).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got your memory management wrong.

In this case it's probably an overreleased `NSMutableData`. Proper management for this object should be done by the property `webData`. You did not post the declaration, yet it should be along the lines:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableData *webData;
```

If you synthesized the accessors they should do the retain/release for you.

To answer why the error happens nevertheless we need more code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it may be help you:

this may be crash due to NULL response data so check your response data and set the following condition for the future purpose:

And synthesize your NSData:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
   if(responseData != NULL) 
   { 
       [responseData setLength:0];
   }
}
```

Comment: `[responseData setLength:0];` does *not* crash if responseData is nil.